# How to cut short multiple if else statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I recently came across a situation where I was working on a huge form with atleast 60 fields and I wanted that form to only submit if all fields were filled and if not, I wanted to show a custom message (Sweetalert) for every field not filled.
For example, If first name was left empty, show the message "Please enter your first name", If country of residence was not selected, show them the message that "Please select your country of residence" so on and so forth.
While I was writing tons of if and else statements to match every field using `document.getElementById()`, this thought of not doing things right came into my mind. I tried searching the web for this but was unable to find a suitable way of doing such things. Can anyone suggest me a better way rather then writing if else statements of 100 lines ?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: eh, well, if statements aren't the right tool for the job for this kind of thing. At least, not on their own. For something as simple as checking whether or not the fields are filled in, you can use the built-in required attribute, or you can use a loop. If each field needs a custom message more than just using the field's label or name, you can add that text as a data attribute of the element or as an element with that text as a child node that you can show.

Comment: Maybe try adding `required` to all the form fields?

Comment: @tehbeardedone that wont show the custom message I need for each field right/?

Comment: the required attribute works quite well

Comment: Nope, but it would eliminate the if/else problem. Do you really need a custom message or would just highlighting the missing fields that are invalid work well enough?

Comment: @KevinB I wont be getting the error messages I want for each field if i use the built in required feature

Comment: Sometimes, the feature you need isn't the one you necessarily want.

Comment: @tehbeardedone I actually need to show custom error messages for each and every field but I also want to reduce the if-else statements.

Comment: I might try adding "Please enter your first name" as a data-prompt attribute (or grab a label object as the subject of your prompt), then grab and loop through all your input fields and check if they're blank and use the data-prompt or label field in your SweetAlert.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a specific class to your form controls you'd be able to retrieve them and iterate through them in order to check which ones are not filled.

Let's say this is your form:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" novalidate>
  <div>
    <label for="control_1">Label_1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="control_1" name="control_1" class="control" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="control_2">Label_2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="control_2" name="control_2" class="control" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="control_3">Label_3:</label>
    <input type="text" id="control_3" name="control_3" class="control" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="control_4">Label_4:</label>
    <select id="control_4" name="control_4" class="control">
      <option value="option_1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option_2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option_3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Then you can use the `.control` class to retrieve all controls and check them:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const controls = document
    .getElementById("myForm")
    .querySelectorAll(".control");

  controls.forEach(control => {
    if (!isControlFilled(control)) {
      console.log(control.id);
      // Do whatever you want with control's id
    }
  });
}

// This is just for illustrative purposes
// Should be adapted to cover all control types
function isControlFilled(control) {
  return control.value ? true : false;
}
```